# Loading model weights in tensorflow changes order of predicted classes

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have a keras model of the following form:

```py
class MyAbstractModel(keras.Model)
   ...
   def predict(self, **kwargs)
      kwargs["x"] = self.preprocess(kwargs["x"])
      super().predict(kwargs)

class MyModel(MyAbstractModel):
   def fit(self, **kwargs)
      kwargs["x"] = self.preprocess(kwargs["x"])
      kwargs["y"] = self.preprocess2(kwargs["y"])
      super().predict(kwargs)

   def save(self, path):
      # I have to save the weights because I need to retain the custom logic in this class
      self.save_weights(path / "weights", save_format="tf")
      with open(path / "vectorizer", "wb") as file:
         joblib.dump({
            "config": self.vecorizer.get_config(),
            "weights": self.vecorizer.get_weights()
         }, file)  # self.vectorizer is of type keras.layers.TextVectorizer

   @classmethod
   def load(cls, path):
      instance = cls()
      instance.load_weights(path / "weights")
      with open(path / "vectorizer", "rb") as file:
         loaded_vec = joblib.load(file)
      self.vectorizer.from_config(loaded_vec["config"])
      self.vectorizer.set_weights(loaded_vec["weights"])
      return instance
```

Note that my model predicts multiple classes with the following head: `keras.layers.Dense(N_CLASSES, activation="softmax", name="classifier")` and for training, I'm converting my classes into the desired format with `keras.utils.to_categorical(label_mapping[y] for y in response)` where `label_mapping` is a dictionary like this: `{"A": 0, "B": 1, "C": 2}`.

Immediately after training the model, I can successfully use it to generate predictions, however, after saving it and reloading it, the order of my classes is all over the place. The raw `predict` method gives me an array of N dimensions (where N=number of classes) but the order in which the probabilities are produced changes every time I reload the model. I've found [this issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4875) which seems to be relevant and I've tried adding `manual_variable_initialization(True)` to my training script, but it didn't help.

I've also noticed that I'm getting a warning `WARNING:tensorflow: Detecting that an object or model or tf.train.Checkpoint is being deleted with unrestored values.` following by a bunch of `Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).classifier.kernel`, etc, but I don't think that is related to the problem. I've traced that warning to [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/43554).

Many thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I've also tried saving the model object with `joblib` and `keras.savel_model` with the custom preprocessing function moved outside of the class but this problem remains!

**EDIT 2:** Hi all, and thank you for looking into this! I think I've found the problem and it turned out to be something silly on my end that is not connected to Keras or Tensorflow at all. It was to do with how I initialized the label names which then affected the order in which the prediction array was returned. I did this:

```py
class Category(enum.Enum):
   A = "A"
   B = "B"
   C = "C"

CATEGORIES = list(map(lambda c: c.value, Category))
```

So `CATEGORIES` produces the values in a different order each time.

Thank you all again, but I'm closing this question.

Comment: Could you try saving weights in .h5 format and see if it behaves similarly?

Comment: there is missing ``kwargs["y"] = self.preprocess2(kwargs["y"])`` in the predict function no ? so the data is different between the train and the predict ! if it's not the issue can you provide a minimum code that reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it turned out to be something silly on my end that is not connected to Keras or Tensorflow at all. It was to do with how I initialized the label names which then affected the order in which the prediction array was returned. I did this:

```py
class Category(enum.Enum):
   A = "A"
   B = "B"
   C = "C"

CATEGORIES = list(map(lambda c: c.value, Category))
```

So `CATEGORIES` produces the values in a different order each time.

Thank you all again, but I'm closing this question.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the vectorizer class? https://keras.io/api/layers/preprocessing_layers/text/text_vectorization/

Try creating a very simple model, no subclassing, that uses your vectorizer and does save/load correctly. I do not know if this Layer has been thoroughly proofed out for model save/load. As you may have noticed, Keras model save/load has been problematic for a very long time.

This tutorial claims to show it working: https://medium.com/deep-learning-with-keras/text-vectorization-use-save-upload-54d65945d222